# Is converting numpy array to .npy format an example of serialization of data?

Tags: python, numpy, serialization

I understand that serialization of data means converting a data structure or object state to a form which can be stored in a file or buffer, can be transmitted, and can be reconstructed later (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/object_oriented_python/object_oriented_python_serialization.htm). Based on this definition, converting a numpy array to .npy format should be serialization of the numpy array data object. However, I could not find this assertion anywhere, when I looked up on the internet. Most of the related links were mentioning about how pickle format does serialization of data in python. My questions is - is converting numpy array to .npz format an example of serialization of a python data object. If not, what are the reasons?

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization):

> In computing, serialization (or serialisation) is the process of
>   translating data structures or object state into a format that can be
>   stored (for example, in a file or memory buffer) or transmitted (for
>   example, across a network connection link) and reconstructed later
>   (possibly in a different computer environment).

And according to [Numpy Doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html#module-numpy.lib.format):

> Binary serialization
>
> **NPY format**
>   A simple **format** for saving numpy arrays to disk with the full
>   information about them.
>
> The `.npy` format is the **standard binary file format** in NumPy for
>   persisting a single arbitrary NumPy array on disk. The format stores
>   all of the shape and dtype information necessary to **reconstruct the**
>   **array correctly even on another machine with a different architecture**.
>
> The .npz format is the standard format for persisting multiple NumPy
>   arrays on disk. A .npz file is a zip file containing multiple .npy
>   files, one for each array.

So, putting this definitions together you can come up with an answer to your question. **Yes**, is a way of serialization. Also the process of storing and reading is [fast](https://towardsdatascience.com/what-is-npy-files-and-why-you-should-use-them-603373c78883)

Answer (score 0):

`np.save(filename, arr)` writes the array to a file.  Since a file a linear structure it is a form of serialization.  But often 'serialization' refers to creating a string that can be sent to a database or over some 'pipeline'.  I think you can `save` to a string buffer, but it takes a bit of trickery.

But in Python most objects have a `pickle` method, which creates a string which can be written to a file. In that sense pickle is a 2 step process - serialize and then write to file.  The pickle for a numpy array is actually a `save` compatible form.  (conversely, `np.save` of a non-array object uses that object's pickle).

`savez` writes a `zip` archive, containing one `npy` file for each array. It may in addition be compressed.  There are OS tools for transferring zip archives to other computers.

Comment: From your answer I understand that `np.save()` results in serialization or array, though reluctantly, and `np.savez` is also a serialization process as it also writes the numpy arrays to a file. Am I correct? I am still not sure about the statements after reading your answer.